# Cannot Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am unable to select "Yes" on the `Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal` option for my Azure AD, even though I have the Global Administrator role. Every time I select yes and hit save I get an "insufficient privileges" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up creating a new user and assigning the Global Administrator role to that user. The new user was then able to change the setting.